# Problems trying to expand USB file system

Tags: raspbian, usb, filesystem

I am having a little bit of a problem expanding my file system on my Pi. I have just used Win32 to "burn" the Raspbian OS onto my 8Gb USB, which I then copied the boot files to my 2Gb SD and changed the root to `root=/dev/sd2`, this works perfectly fine and Rasbian boots but I have about 4.86 Gb of unallocated space on my USB. I would like to expand my file system onto the rest of my USB drive. I have tried `resize2fs/dev/sda3` (sda3 being a partition I created from the unallocated) and it gives me a messaging saying that the file system is already size, which is were I am confused. So I removed the partition and have it unallocated and try the command again `resize2fs /dev/sda2` and I get the same message (but with a different size). I am lost on how to expand it. I want the `/dev/sd2/` to take up all of the 6 something gigs available.

I tried [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14310/raspberry-pi-expand-file-system-on-usb) but it didn't work.[image]

Comment: Just curious, what happens when you try and resize the partition using gparted? If the OS is on the USB stick, then its best to resize it on another PC. Possibly using the gparted boot disc or another Linux system.

Comment: @ppumkin well good sir. This is the second problem that you have helped me fix. MANY thanks. Spent about a day trying to get the file system expanded and well, i couldn't. Anyway this worked perfect. Booted up my Linux PC I had in the corner and **boom** resized via Gparted. Thank you and Cheers!!

Comment: No problem at all :) This was the first time I answered a question in the comments :) Just to improve stats I will convert the comment to an answer otherwise it will stay open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem most probably exists because you are trying to resize the OS volume and it is locked.

If you have access to an Ubuntu or other Linux desktop I would suggest using `gparted` on another system.

You can also download a [gparted live disk](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php) - Burn it and boot from it.

[image]

1. If you have a swap partition on the USB then the **FIRST STEP** is to move it to the end of the drive

   1. Select the SWAP and click resize/move.
   2. You should be able to visually drag the partition to the far left.(make sure NOT to resize it by any mistake)
   3. Accept
2. Click on the system partition and then again do a resize/move option.

   2. This time you will drag the right edge of the partition, to resize it, all the way  to the far right side.
   3. Accept
3. Click apply

   3. Let it do its magic ...

So once that is done put the USB Stick card in the Pi and boot it up!